# How to change Title and Desscription in the website that build with reactjs

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-native, seo

i have my website in react java. it was built very earlier. now i am trying to do SEO for my website, but i cannot give a separate SEO title and description for each page. even if i enter the syntax, google is not recognizing it. as, when i click "View Source" for any pages, it opens only the view source of the home page. no other pages are showing in the view source.

when i ask this with some tech persons, he is saying like, the entire website is built like a single landing page, so it will be like that only.

if so, how others can do SEO for their websites?.

is there any solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try react-meta-tags npm library to add meta tags in every component as you want

```
npm install react-meta-tags --save
```

**Lets import react and react-meta-tags at first**

```
import React from 'react';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

//lets make a componet having some meta tags structure like this
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <MetaTags>
            <title>Page 1</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Some description." />
            <meta property="og:title" content="MyApp" />
            <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg" />
          </MetaTags>
          <div className="content"> Some Content </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

At First you should try This:-
for react or simple html site the  procedure is same
In your public directory > index.html inside modify them

**for title**
To Give Title We should Add Our tile in between `<title> my title </title>` Tag

**for description**
add this tag between

```
<meta name=”description” content=”This is my site description”>
```

Comment: HI,. i can able to input those, But,.. after updating,. when i open the view source of that page, it opens the view source of the Home page only. because of that, google is not crawling the page of those pages.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what youve created etc.. however adding metadata on your page can be done easily using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

If you want pages to be indexable by a search engine, you will need to have a SPA mode and you will also need to render the page using SSR (static site rendering).  Otherwise, the Google crawler won't be able to read it

If you are NextJS or some framework like then it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a site built in AngularJS.

To solve the problem we create a pre-render service using [this](https://github.com/prerender/prerender) lib.

We routed the crawler traffic to the pre-render service.

If done correctly, google & other crawlers will always get fully rendered pages side stepping the SPA issue.